# how to use @CanActivate in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Im have a `UserService` and have A profile component, i have function in my `Userservice` and i want check if user is login the route can be active somthing like this :

```
@CanActivate((userService: UserService) => userService.checkLogin())
```

how to use `CanActivate` like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@CanActivate()` gets called before the `Component` is created, so you just have to return true or false in there if you want to route to the component or not.

```js
import {appInjector} from './app-injector';
// ...
@CanActivate((next, prev) => {
    let injector = appInjector();
    let userService: UserService = injector.get(UserService);

    // if the checkLogin() method returns a boolean, you can just return it
    return userService.checkLogin();
}
```

You'll need a `app-injector.ts` to hold the current injector from bootstrapping:

```js
let appInjectorRef;

export const appInjector:any = (injector = false) => {
    if (!injector) {
        return appInjectorRef;
    }

    appInjectorRef = injector;

    return appInjectorRef;
};
```

In your `bootstrap` call just store the injector:

```js
import {appInjector} from './app-injector';
// ...
bootstrap(App, [
    [...],
    UserService
]).then((appRef) => appInjector(appRef.injector));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if user login,

```
@Component({selector: ... })
@CanActivate(()=>console.log('Should the component Activate?'))
class AppComponent {

}
```

And go through [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html)

Comment: And go through CanActivate ! 404 :)

Comment: It might be down check leter

Answer (score 0):

[@CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/CanActivate-decorator.html) is a function decorator that takes one parameter that is a function. This function returns boolean or Promise. So you can use it like:

```
@CanActivate ((next, prev) => {
    return this.userService.checkLogin();
})
```

if your checkLogin() method returns Promise, e.g,

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // some code...
    resolve(true);
});
```

Don't forget to inject your UserService through component constructor

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private userService : UserService) { }
}
```